# How can I improve this question and get answers I want?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, down-votes

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this question? How can I improve it?

> I'm in the field of EEE but I'm not specializing in software
>   engineering. Yesterday, i had an impromptu idea to develop a software
>   to integrate smartphone with a laptop. However, without any software
>   development background, I'm quite clueless on how to start or where
>   can I learn it?
>
> Can i discuss the idea freely and initiate an open source project?
>   (But how to initiate that if I can't be the technical lead of the
>   project?)
>
> Could someone please point me to some self-learning sources / platform
>   for project discussion? :) Thank you!

It has been voted down and stated as "possible duplicate" of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/how-to-recruit-programmers-for-an-open-source-project-and-kick-start-it

But I can't find my answers there. What I want to know is 
1. How to initiate a project if I can't be the technical lead?
2. What is the suitable platform for project discussion? (is it on Programmers.stackexchange?) 
3. What should I learn / equip myself with in order to start the project?

Also, what is the reason for downvote? Often, many people downvote without a reason. (how can I improve without knowing what's wrong?) Perhaps, it should be made a rule to state the reason when they choose to downvote. :( it's really hurtful.

Comment: All of these questions are adequately answered here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the suitable platform for project discussion?

I think that this is part of the problem with the question in that very discussion oriented questions increase noise on the site, and make it harder to build content.  Questions should be answerable, but a discussion is a series of questions, and then discovery leading to more questions.  It doesn't do well in the Q&A format we have on this site.

I cite the [Help document](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/dont-ask):

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

If you need a discussion then I advise checking out our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), it is intended for such things.

> How to initiate a project if I can't be the technical lead?

I actually think this is a great question by itself and you should ask it.  The problem is that I don't see where you are actually asking this or it just isn't clear you are asking this.  If this is something you really want to know then it is getting drowned out by unrelated problems you are bringing up in your Question.

> What should I learn / equip myself with in order to start the project?

This is considered an Off Topic question on Programmers.  I cite the [Help document](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic) on Off Topic questions:

> [you should not ask ...] what language/technology you should learn next, including which technology is better,

I think that overall if you ask a new question focused around point number 2, then you can get some good answers, but your other problems should go to chat and see if anybody wants to discuss them with you first.

Comment: Thank you for the clear clarification. :) i can now better sort out what questions I can ask and what i shouldn't.